# Why jsoup selector for ID and class does not work for me here?

Tags: jsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to parse [this page](http://answers.yahoo.com/search/search_result?p=Angel) from Yahoo can try to fetch all the questions' url.

I use jsoup, but these selectors will select nothing, why?

```
doc.select("#yan-questions h3 a")
doc.select(".question-title a")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the reason now. It's because that site may send different web pages according to different user agents, and when I didn't include the `User-Agent` HTTP header, the response will not have some `id`s.

This problem is solved when I add this line to the HTTP request:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101
```